# Метод main и его функции

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! 
Возник такой вопрос: " Почему из метода `main` можно вызывать только `static` методы ?

Comment: наверное потому, что он сам `static`, не?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод main сам static, а значит из него можно вызывать только static методы. Это связано с тем, что статические члены (поля, методы) не принадлежат конкретно какому-то объекту этого класса, а являются общими для всего класса. По причине недоступности указателя this статические поля и методы не могут обращаться к нестатическим полям и методам напрямую, так как для обращения к статическим полям и методам достаточно имени класса, в котором они определены.